# Recycler View Item with Constraint Layout- Pushed Aside During Run Time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I created constraint layout for recycler view item. It looks fine during preview, however the item pushed aside during run time. I tried by using other item view with constraint layout which worked before, it works fine and I am not sure why it behaves like this during run time.

[image]

Recycler View Item Code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pastorderdate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="@{order.date}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="2/3/2020" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pastOrderAmount"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            app:priceStringOverview="@{order.amount}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pastorderdate"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pastorderdate"
            tools:text="RM50.80" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Recycler View Code

```
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/pastorderslist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            pastorderlist = "@{viewmodel.pastorders}"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pastordertitle"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.492" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with constraint layout and what worked for me was on the `onCreateViewHolder` of the adapter, I replaced the Inflater from `LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, null)` to `LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)`

Comment: I am not sure how I can implement in my code. I used Databinding in my code

Answer (score 0):

Please use following for the constraints:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pastorderdate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/pastOrderAmount"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pastOrderAmount"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pastorderdate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It should work

Comment: The ```pastOrderAmount``` displayed, however the ```pastOrderAmount``` is not displayed

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it. However now both fields cannot be displayed. It only happens when it is a recycler view item. Its fine when I do on the fragment layout.

Comment: May I ask, how is Recycler View Code interacting with the Recycler View Item Code